# returning initializer list mechanism

Tags: c++, c++11

What mechanism is involved, if when returning types, that are constructible from initializer lists, I don't specify the type I am returning, as in:

```
std::array<int, 3> make_array()
{
  return { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

instead of

```
std::array<int, 3> make_array()
{
  return std::array<int, 3>{ 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

Are there any performance penalties involved, if I return the initializer list without specifying a type? Am I actually returning an array, that is converted into a `std::array`?

Comment: It seems too tidy to be without penalty, doesn't it? ;-) But I'm sure `litb` is correct. This is extra useful with 'uniform initialisation': we can use this notation with custom types without having to code a constructor taking an `std::initializer_list`: the compiler implicitly converts the braced list to the normal ctor. So, we save the repetition of writing the type again on return.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are no performance penalties involved. The return value is constructed equivalent to

```
std::array<int, 3> x = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

There is not even a single copy or move of an `std::array` instance involved.

Answer (score 2):

The mechanism is just a constructor:

```
struct X {};

struct Y {
    Y(X);
};

Y f() {
    X x;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: ...how does this relate to initialiser lists?

Comment: @underscore_d in this example `Y` stands for the `std::array<int, 3>` from op's question.

Comment: @ljleb and no initialiser list is used, so I must repeat my question.

Comment: @underscore_d I think the point Bartosz wanted to make was that `std::initializer_list<int>` (which `X` seems to stand for) is just passed to the appropriate constructor of `std::array<int, 3>` (which `Y` seems to stand for) and the resulting value is just returned to the caller. I'm not quite sure how to interpret this code snippet differently.