# Returning a braced initializer list from a function: What is it compiled down to?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

Here's a small piece of code for example.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct coordinate {
    int x, y;
};

coordinate shift(coordinate p, int offset) {
    return {p.x + offset, p.y + offset};
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    coordinate p {1, 2};
    coordinate p_s = shift(p, 3);
    std::cout << "x: " << p_s.x << "\ty: " << p_s.y;
    return 0;
}
```

In the function `shift`, we see that the return statement is seemingly returning an initializer list.

While I understand what that means semantically, I'm looking to confirm if I understand what it is compiled down to.

Does the compiler interpret the `shift` function as this?

```cpp
shift(coordinate p, int offset) {
    coordinate p_ {p.x + offset, p.y + offset};
    return p_;
}
```

If not, then how?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [returning initializer list mechanism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240404/returning-initializer-list-mechanism)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is similar, although it seems more natural to write the equivalence as a constructor expression:

```
 return coordinate{p.x + offset, p.y + offset};
```

which makes it obvious that it is not much more than syntactic sugar. That is, it is not returning an initializer list, but rather returning a new object of the indicated type constructed using the braced-init-list syntax.

Note that copy elision applies, so when the return value is assigned to a newly constructed `coordinate`, the intermediate `coordinate` will not be constructed (or might not be constructed, in older c++ versions).

Comment: @TusharRakheja: "Copy elision" is the name for this procedure in the C++ standard; it's explained at paragraph 31 of section 12.8 of the C++14 draft, and with slight wording changes in the current draft. Both are available free on the ISO C++ site, https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard

Answer (score 5):

You are not returning a "braced" initializer list, you are returning a struc that was constructed with a braced initializer list, which is a temporary object, therefore RVO will apply.

Nothing to worry.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I wanted to upvote it, but SO thinks I'm too new to start doing that.

Comment: Your kind words are enough :)

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but... `shift()` returns a temporary `coordinate`, and `p_s` is then copy constructed from that temporary coordinate.

(Most compilers will likely skip the middle-man, however, and pass a hidden reference so that `shift()` constructs `p_s` directly, I believe.)

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind explaining the hidden reference part a bit more?

Comment: It's a way that RVO might be implemented behind the scenes, basically.  I just forgot the term for it.