# How " return {...}; " works in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to implement a String. I want to convert the String to lower case, so called `boost::to_lower_copy(m_s)`. In fact, `m_s` is of type `std::string`. My question is how `return {boost::to_lower_copy(m_s)};` works in function `to_lower_copy()`. How could it return a String type?
Thanks a lot.

```
class String {
    std::string m_s;
public:
    String(const std::string s) : m_s(s) { }
    String to_lower_copy() const {
        return {boost::to_lower_copy(m_s)};
    }
};
```

Comment: `return {...}` calls `std::string{...}`, and returns the newly constructed string.  It does this because the compiler knows the function needs to return a std::string.

Comment: @RichardCritten, why answer in a comment? You should convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: @RichardCritten Did you mean `String`?

Comment: @LogicStuff I did, good catch - just too late to edit my comment.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240404/returning-initializer-list-mechanism

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487065/what-does-return-statement-mean-in-c11/39487164

Answer (score 1):

`attr(optional) return braced-init-list ;` is alternative return statement syntax introduced in C++11. It copy-list-initializes the return value of the function. The compiler knows the type that the function returns, because it is part of the declaration.